# NextJs Kubernetes Nginx Ingress routing problem

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, next.js, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a next.js application that is being deployed to an on premises kubernetes cluster. when we build, we do a static build and convert everything into html with `next build && next export`. Everything appears to be working if you click a link on the page and you let next.js router display the page. It updates the url and the view loads as expected.

The problem is when you try to navigate to the view directly. For example navigating to `example.com` works, but navigating directly to `example.com/about` throws a `404`.

If i append a `.html` onto the route it does display the page but who wants that.

The nginx ingress and service manifest files are the following:

`ingress.yml`

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  labels:
    tenant: example
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: nginx
                port:
                  number: 80
```

`service.yml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: example-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
```

Comment: If possible can you add service manifests to the question?

Comment: @DharaniDharGolladasari I have updated the question with the service manifest.